# Handling infinity gradients while using numpy gradient

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, gradient

I am using the `numpy.gradient()` to evaluate the gradients wherein I have points where the `x` coordinates are constant for a few successive points. It is leading to `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in scalar divide....` while using `np.gradient(y, x)`.

In this context, I am thinking of using the arc tangent of the gradient to avoid infinity or zero-division errors, but not sure how I can proceed.

How do we evaluate gradients (or otherwise their arc tangents) for this kind of data?

A minimal code to reproduce the behaviour.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import path

CSD = path.dirname(__file__)

x = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])
y = np.array([0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 9.0, 15.0, 20.0, 30.0])
dy_dx = np.gradient(y, x)

fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.plot(x, y, color="b", marker="o", ms=10.0, label="y")
axs.plot(x, dy_dx, color="r", marker="*", ms=15.0, label="dy/dx")
axs.legend(loc='best')
axs.grid()
plt.savefig(path.join(CSD, "handling_inf_grad_raw.png"))
plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Based on the data I would say this is completely expected and fine behavior. In these situations you can either do nothing or just suppress the warning using `np.errstate(divide="ignore"):` (see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html)

Comment: Consider some kind of spline interpolation, or a boxcar averaging before differentiation.